# Show read and unread messages

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to replicate an email function(how a general email does it)  which shows when a department read and doesnt read a message. so the scenario is this. I have a department "GA registry" which send messages when the department(GA) has any sort of changes. The receiving departments are IT, Facilities and HR.

When GA sends their message (which is sent from a form in the database) The table that stores the messages to allow the departments to see it is called "NEWS" and the fields are

- Postdate(sysdate)
- Category
- Details

so in a classic report i have

```
select POSTDATE,CATEGORY,
       DETAILS
    from NEWS
```

Each department has their own login username and password for other things within the database, so they will see things that only pertain to them.. But in the news area all departments suppose to see every news being posted..

What i would like is for each department to see when they read or did not read the posted messages like how email does it.. so even if IT reads a message if when Facilities log in and they didnt read the message it would be of an unread nature(whether highlighted , color coded etc)

Comment: What exactly do you expect from Stack Overflow community?

Comment: i would like is for each department to see when they read or did not read the posted messages